# need to add header to message which will be sent to IBM MQ websphere

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am not sure how to add message header to the message which we send to IBM MQ websphere server. Below is code I tried to use but I get exception :

**Creating Connection to the server**

```
        qMgr = new MQQueueManager(queueMgr, props);

        int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF
                | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT |  MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;
        queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);
        message = new MQMessage();
```

**Sending the Message**

```
public String sendMessage(){

      MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();


        message.format                  = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
        message.feedback                = MQC.MQFB_NONE;
        message.messageType             = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;

        message.messageId     = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
        message.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;

            message.writeString(sMsg);
            queue.put(message,pmo);
}
```

I tried with the below code to add Header

```
((TextMessage)message).setStringProperty(header_name,header_value);
```

But i get the exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.mq.MQMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.TextMessage`.

And I am Stuck here. If this is solved then the riddle is completed.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you mixing Java SE MQ API calls with JMS calls?

From the manual, in the section 'Handling message properties' for WebSphere MQ classes for Java:

> Function calls to process message handles have no equivalent in
>   WebSphere MQ classes for Java. To set, return, or delete message
>   handle properties, use methods of the MQMessage class.

Therefore, why aren't you simply doing:

```
MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
pmo.options = MQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT;

message.format        = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
message.feedback      = MQC.MQFB_NONE;
message.messageType   = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
message.messageId     = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
message.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;

message.setStringProperty(header_name,header_value)

message.writeString(sMsg);
queue.put(message,pmo);
```

One final note, please do not reply saying you can't do that, as you are using WMQ v6.  WMQ v6 went out of support almost 2 years ago, so you must upgrade to WMQ v7.* (preferably to WMQ v7.5).