# Adding Personalized data to MQ RFH2 Header

Tags: java, ibm-mq

HI i am trying to add data in the RFH2 MQ header.
The format for the data which i want is:

```
struc id : RFH
version:2
encoding:546
CodedCharSetid:437
Format:MQSTR
Flags:0
NameValeCCSID:1208
NamevalueLen:56
Namevaluedata:<mcd><msd>jms_text<Msd><Type>Hello</type></mcd>
NamvalueLen:56
NameValuedata:<jms><dst></dst></jms>
NamevalueLen:56
NameValuedata:<usr>Hi</usr>
```

I have the following code, but i am not understanding how to add the **NameValueLen** and **NAMEVALUEDATA** part. Can some check the code which i have written and guide me further on this?

```
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
msg.format = MQC.MQFMT_RF_HEADER_2; // Msg Format
msg.writeString(MQC.MQRFH_STRUC_ID); // StrucId 
msg.writeInt4(MQC.MQRFH_VERSION_2); // Version 
msg.writeInt4(MQC.MQRFH_STRUC_LENGTH_FIXED_2 + folderLength + 4); 
msg.writeInt4(MQC.MQENC_NATIVE); // Encoding 
msg.writeInt4(MQC.MQCCSI_DEFAULT); // CodedCharacterSetId 
msg.writeString(MQC.MQFMT_NONE); // Format (content) 
msg.writeInt4(MQC.MQRFH_NO_FLAGS); // Flags 
msg.writeInt4(1208); // NameValueCCSID = UTF-8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [need to add header to message which will be sent to IBM MQ websphere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557820/need-to-add-header-to-message-which-will-be-sent-to-ibm-mq-websphere)

Comment: MQ handles populating the RFH2 header when a JMS application reads a message sent from a non-JMS application.   If you want more control you can use the IBM MQ Classes for JMS instead of the IBM MQ Classes for Java.

Comment: @JoshMc can you please tell me how to use that?
any link which can give me proper understanding of MQ

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what tool you are using but it is confusing the issue.  MQRFH2 has "folders".  The 1st folder is ALWAYS "mcd".  The 2nd folder is "jms".  All folders after that are optional.

Note: The "usr" folder is where you put your user data.

Why are you not using the [MQRFH2 class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/headers/MQRFH2.html) in MQ?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030950_.htm

i.e.  Here's how you should be doing it:

```
MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();
MQRFH2 rfh2 = new MQRFH2();

rfh2.setEncoding(CMQC.MQENC_NATIVE);
rfh2.setCodedCharSetId(CMQC.MQCCSI_INHERIT);
rfh2.setFormat(CMQC.MQFMT_STRING);
rfh2.setNameValueCCSID(1208);
rfh2.setFieldValue("usr", "somefield", "somedata");

try
{
   rfh2.write(mqMsg);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
   System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Note: In the above code, folders "mcd" and "jms" will be automatically created and populated.

You can blast all 3 folders ("mcd", "jms" and "usr") in 1 shot.  I don't recommend it unless you know what you are doing.

```
rfh2.setFolderStrings(new String[]{"<mcd><Msd>jms_text</Msd></mcd>",
                                   "<jms><Dst>queue:///TEST.Q1</Dst><Pri>0</Pri></jms>",
                                   "<usr><somefield>somedata</somefield></usr>"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info man, can you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742444/sending-ibm-mq-message-along-with-mqmd-and-mqrfh2-headers/43755393#43755393